I have integrated react-native-web, whenever i wanted import like , import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable' it will throw error
I have integrated react-native-web, whenever i wanted import like , import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable' it wienter image description herell throw error , Please help me, i am beginner in react-native as well as react native web
this is my code enter image description here
